# Do Labryinth Enchantments affect Vaal versions of skills?

Tags: path-of-exile

If I have an Labryinth enchantment on my helm like "Cyclone attacks 15% faster", would enchantment affect Vaal versions of the skill as well?   I'm curious because there's an Ancestral Warchief enchantment I'd like to get it but don't know if it'd apply to Vaal AW as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes.](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1620191#p13021792) Vaal skill gems are still technically also the original, so all of the helm enchantments work with the vaal variety of gems.

Comment: Note:  This was true even before Vaal and non-Vaal skill gems were combined into single items.